# A natural number $n$ is called "good" when it is equal to multiplying two consecutive natural numbers . Is there ...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A natural number $n$ is called "good" when it is equal to multiplying two consecutive natural numbers. Is there a set of $1401$ good numbers that add up to a good number?

I don't have any usefull idea how should I start and how to prove it , could you help me guys , or i must have idea to ask question?

Comment: 2*1401=2802; 53*54=2862. 2862-2802=(6-2)*15.

Comment: @max what is this bro ?

Comment: Think about it, bro.

Comment: Why do you want to solve this? Why 1401 in particular? The question is lacking in context. Please check out [our guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: Your good number $g$ are simply twice a triangular number. $g=n(n+1)=2T_{n}$. These numbers are on the diagonal below the main diagonal (that of the squares) in the multiplication table $(2,6,12,20,30,42...)$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n) = n(n+1)$ be the $n$th good number.
First we note that $a_n$ is always even, and that
$$f(n)-f(n-1) = 2n.$$

Now start with any good number $f(k)$ with $k > 2$.  Note that $f(k)>2k+1$ Hence by the previous facts we have
$$  f\left (\frac{f(k)}{2}\right) - f\left(\frac{f(k)}{2} -1\right) = f(k). $$
Which means that
$$ f\left (\frac{f(k)}{2}\right) = f(k) + f\left(\frac{f(k)}{2} -1\right) .$$

We can then let $j = \frac{f(k)}{2}$ and repeat the process again to get
$$ f\left (\frac{f(j)}{2}\right) = f\left (\frac{f(k)}{2}\right) + f\left(\frac{f(j)}{2} -1\right) .$$
And hence that
$$ f\left (\frac{f(j)}{2}\right) = f(k) + f\left(\frac{f(k)}{2} -1\right) + f\left(\frac{f(j)}{2} -1\right) .$$
We can then repeat this process as much as we want to get sums of any size.

For a concrete example first pick $k = 3$. Then $f(k) = 12$ and so

$$f(6) = f(3) + f(5).$$

But then since $f(6)= 42$
$$f(21) = f(20) + f(3) + f(5).$$
And so on.

Note that all the good numbers in your sum are unique.